# How to correctly deploy and scale applications using docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, elasticsearch, scalability

I am studying to use docker to deploy a nodejs app with mongo DB and elastic search. I want that it be scalable,  the nodejs server and the elastic search server. I found docker. But I don't know how I design the project structure. I found aws ec2. I think that it would work fine. But, my doubt is, how I can deploy this? Is the best option deploy elastic search separately from nodejs container? Or I can deploy all that in a single docker container on ec2 instance? Is docker useful for deploy large applications?  I googled but I can't find anything really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use docker for your storage engine make sure you use docker volumes to store your data. [Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/)

I would however recommend running mongoDB on a node without docker, simply due to disk performance. I'd probably do the same for elastic search tbh.

EDIT: And yes, seperate your services over seperate docker instances. Also take a look at [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/docker/).

Comment: humm, but the costs would be more expensive, don't?

Comment: Well more expensive then having it on a single instance, but it scales well. You could put elastic and mongo on a EC2 instance and then use ECS for your app (all inside a VPC to keep it nice and secure) to start if you starting super small but want to be able to scale out.

Comment: Do you know a cheap service for this? Could i use aws ec2?

Comment: For mongo/elastic? You could use a m5.large for mongo/elastic and then a ecs m3.medium/t2.micro instance for node.js duties. Benefit of using docker is  you can go from a t2 to a larger instance easily :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run and scale all of them as separate services:

- run an elasticsearch cluster on either docker hosts or k8s
- run mongod service either on docker or kubernetes
- run your app either on docker host or k8s and use the above two services

Currently I am running all these as separate services on docker hosts , but I am planning to run them all on kubernetes to scale them without custom automation scripts.